# How to generate automatic numbering of output files in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename, file-rename

I have a bunch of files say,

- xxx111.txt
- xxx112.txt
- xxx113.txt

I want to remove the last 3 characters of all the file names and I'm using this script

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set X=3
for %%f in (*) do if %%f neq %~nx0 (
set "filename=%%~nf"
set "filename=!filename:~,-%X%!"
ren "%%f" "!filename!%%~xf"
)
popd
pause
```

This runs perfectly when the output filenames are different. However, in the above case all file will be output as `xxx.txt` and the script throws me the error

> "A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found".

Is there any way to tweak this so that duplicate files will be renamed and maybe numbered 1,2,3...?

Unfortunately I cannot install any other software.

Comment: Editing question to "DELETE PLEASE" won't help you in deleting the question. Please don't vandalise the post. User contributions are licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). Please read the terms. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set X=3
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /A:-D /B') do if "%%f" neq "%~NX0" (
   set "filename=%%~Nf"
   set "filename=!filename:~,-%X%!"
   if exist "!filename!%%~Xf" call :getNewName "%%~Xf"
   ren "%%f" "!filename!%%~Xf"
)
popd
pause
goto :EOF


:getNewName ext
set i=0
:nextNum
   set /A i+=1
if exist "%filename%%i%%~1" goto nextNum
set "filename=%filename%%i%"
exit /B
```

You should not use plain `for %%f` command when renaming files. Depending on where the new names are placed in the list of original names, they may be processed a second time by the `for %%f`. Always use `for /F` for renaming.